# Managed to unmanaged code, DWORD value to LPVOID

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

I have a manged process which passes an address value as a DWORD.  I wish to use this DWORD value in a thread function which requires the param be passed as an LPVOID, how can I pass the value without it becoming garbled?  This is not the real code but as much of it as I can remember!

```
void incoming(DWORD addr)
{
    CreateThread(...threadfunc, addr...);
}

DWORD WINAPI threadfunc(LPVOID param)
{
  DWORD _addr = param
}
```

The problem is the receiving threadfunc the addr value is garbled so when I use ReadProcessMemory() for example it is now rubbish!

Thanks.

Comment: What is this `addr` pointer pointing to?

Comment: This is asking for problems on 64 bit systems. A 64 bits address value just won't fit in a DWORD. You cannot prevent it from being garbled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the managed process to pass the pointer to `incoming` as [System.IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx).  This is the standard way to pass pointer values to unmanaged APIs.

> The IntPtr type can be used by
>   languages that support pointers, and
>   as a common means of referring to data
>   between languages that do and do not
>   support pointers.

As noted this will fail on Win64 - you really need to change the `incoming` parameter to be of type `INT_PTR`.

Comment: Steve could you answer this question please.  Ok, so I hard coded the address value into the thread.  This address is valid if I exclude all of the thread code and returns the expected value.  But as soon (with the hard coded address within the thread) as I run it as a thread it returns junk!  Why has the memory address become invalid?  Is the thread looking at a different address space?

Comment: I did work this out Steve, I was using the wrong CreateThread method which is why I was getting junk.  The pointer was correct and annoyingly enough the thread worked.  Thanks for the help.